# Sent emails not visible under Task object in salesforce Lightning

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, send-email, emailmessage, activityhistory

I created a flow which triggers when a task is closed and sents an email through email action. The flow is working and email is received in mail box but I cannot find the sent emails in salesforce Task record. How and where can I find the sent emails for task object.

I tried searching with the subject in salesforce but no luck.

Any suggestions would be of great help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is limitation in salesforce, Kindly review details [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdig2UAB/workflow-email-alerts-to-contacts-should-be-recordable-as-activity-history?_ga=2.141876850.1134554784.1662990607-602491664.1654971272).

However, you can check [workaround](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000DeQSASA3) mentioned to log an activity for email tracking.